# JMockit test not working

Tags: testing, jmockit

I have a test class which I try to run, but getting error.

```
public class MyHelperTest {

    @Tested
    MyHelper MyHelperTestObject;

    @Mocked
    MyData myData;

    @Test
    public void setMyData(){

    MyData myData = new MyData();

    new MockUp<MyHelper>() {

        @Mock
        public MyData setMyData(){ 
        myData.setName("IFTest");
        myData.setValue("IFValue");
        return myData;
        }

    };

    String name = myData.getName();
    assertEquals("IFTest", name);
    } // end setMyData

  } // end test
```

When I run this test, I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: but was:
>   at uk.co.MyHelperTest.setMyData(MyHelperTest.java)

Comment: Have you tried to use the annotation: @RunWith(JMockit.class) public class MyHelperTest {

Comment: @Ish Fady you need to declare a Expectations block in order to tell the mock how to behave